# How to make d3.js force layout gravity rectangular?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, force-layout, physics-engine

In d3.js force layout, giving a gravity value makes layout circular.

[image]
However, I'd like to make force layout rectangular, while nodes have a negative charge and **even distance**. (like above)

Is there any way to make force layout rectangular?

Can I achieve this by modifying tick function?

Here is my code:

```js
var background = d3.select('.background');

var width = background.node().getBoundingClientRect().width,
 height = background.node().getBoundingClientRect().height;

var nodes = d3.range(50).map(function(d, i) {
  return {
        text: "Hello"
  };
 });

var messages = background.selectAll('.message')
 .data(nodes)
 .enter()
  .append('div')
  .attr('class', 'message')
  .text(d => d.text)
  .each(function(d, i) {
   d.width = this.getBoundingClientRect().width;
   d.height = this.getBoundingClientRect().height;
  });

var force = d3.layout.force()
 .gravity(1/88)
 .charge(-50)
 .nodes(nodes)
 .size([width, height]);

messages.call(force.drag);

force.on('tick', function(e) {
 messages.each(d => {
  d.x = Math.max(0, Math.min(width - d.width, d.x));
  d.y = Math.max(0, Math.min(height - d.height, d.y));
 });
 
 messages.style('left', d => `${d.x}px`)
  .style('top', d => `${d.y}px`);
});

force.start();
```

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.background {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  border: 1px solid #007aff;
}
.message {
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  border-radius: 100vh;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #007aff;
  position: absolute;
}
.boundary {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div class="background">
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Yes, there is. Yes, it involves modifying the tick function. However, nobody here will write code just to show how to do it (I mean I won't), and an answer without a code in this case is meaningless. Therefore, post **your code** to create the force, with the tick function, so we just have to modify it.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Oh, I see. I agree with you. I have updated my post with my code! Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, edit 3: in d3v4, [forceCollide](https://github.com/d3/d3-force/blob/master/README.md#forceCollide) can be used to set minimum distances between the nodes, if you then use a positive strength, this draws the nodes together, helping set them an even distance apart (although it looks better for circles than rectangles):

```
var force = d3.forceSimulation(nodes)
.force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength(-10))
.force("collide", d3.forceCollide(30).strength(1).iterations(1))
.force('x', d3.forceX(width/2).strength(0.5))
.force('y', d3.forceY(height/2).strength(10));
```

Assuming the nodes are in a rectangular svg, limiting them to within the centre of the SVG can help even out the edges:

```
position.nodes(nodes).on('tick', function ticks() {
        nodes.attr("cx", function(d) {
            return d.x = Math.max(20, Math.min(width + 20, d.x))
        }).attr("cy", function(d) {
            return d.y = Math.max(20, Math.min(height + 20, d.y));
        })
    });
```

and playing around with the force strengths can help draw them in along the y-axis:

```
var position = d3.forceSimulation(nodes).force("charge", d3.forceManyBody())
.force('x', d3.forceX(width/2).strength(1))
.force('y', d3.forceY(height/2).strength(5));
```

[fiddle here.](https://jsfiddle.net/ohouston/62hq3dc9/)

It seems that the forces are a lot more customisable in v4 than v3, I think forceCollide integrated some workarounds into the library. So, you can try and find a v3 workaround, or maybe look into upgrading to v4.

In v3 I played around with the gravity, charge and limiting x and y to maintain the nodes in the box a bit better, [fiddle here.](https://jsfiddle.net/ohouston/j8g64s2d/) But I don't know enough about v3 to improve it much beyond that.

Comment: Thanks! I should have checked d3.js v4. 'forceX/Y' methods are very useful for me.